# What financial instruments are under development for Bitcoin?

Tags: development, currencies, finance

**I'm thinking here specifically of instruments that take a Bitcoin-like approach to trusted parties, eliminating them wherever possible** and typically built with Bitcoin as their platform.  (As opposed to simply having a real-world trusted entity issue a Bitcoin-containing or Bitcoin-related financial instrument in the traditional method).

Financial instruments include things like bonds, stocks, contracts, additional currencies, etc.

For example, I know jgarzik was working on [smartcoin](https://github.com/jgarzik/smartcoin#readme) for a while (has development stopped?) and there are things like this you can do with [coloured coins](http://www.bitcoinx.org/).  Can anyone offer some insight on what is actually being developed re: these and other approaches, and especially what has reached an implemented, usable level?

Comment: not sure if this is what your looking for, but [ripple](https://ripple.com/) is doing some cool things along these lines

Comment: Does Ripple actually add any new financial instruments other than currencies?  In general, though, I'm talking about development which uses Bitcoin as the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of people that we know about and probably many more that we don't know about are developing a diversity of financial instruments for bitcoin. What instruments exactly will depend on your definition of instrument.

Here is an interesting one:

[cvToken](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=197799.0):
An effort to stabilize the bitcoin price by pegging a token backed by a basket of commodities to it.

Comment: Yeah, I heard about this at the Bitcoin conference.  Although I think they are trying to stabilise the *token*, not the bitcoin price (can someone correct me on that?)